# How to uploads file in order they were selected using multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am able upload multiple files using multer from a single input form. I am storing the filename with an id in a sqlite table but it seems the files are not being uploaded in order they were selected rather it seems random.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: './public/uploads/',
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
}
});


// Init upload images
const uploadImg = multer({
storage: storage,
limits: {fileSize: 3000000},
fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    checkFileTypeImage(file, cb);
}
}).any();
```

how can i make it upload files beginning with the first file selected?

Comment: I would expect files to be uploaded in parallel actually. Is that not the case?

Comment: yes, file are being uploaded parallely hence, the SQL table is filled randomly.  but I need to display them in order. If they would upload in order their metadata would sit in my sql table in order and I could just run through the table without adding extra code in my front end.

Comment: If your users choose multiple files from the classic file selection dialogue that the browser opens, there is no notion of any order. You would need to provide multiple single file input fields. These will also allow you to retrieve an order.